# Fresh Install Windows 7 64bit on Latest i7 cpu with UEFI bios ( Hangs at disk.sys)

Tags: windows-7, bios

I installed a fresh 64 bit Windows 7 with UEFI support injected into it.
I successfully installed from a USB drive.

In bios, i have SATA set to : AHCI
Boot Mode UEFI (only option available)
Secure boot : Disabled

When windows boots, it hangs at the windows logo.  I switched to Safe mode to see where it is hanging and it is as DISK.SYS

How do i get past this current road block?

Comment: Support for install of Windows 7 was deprecated starting with skylake processors....https://wccftech.com/intel-skylake-remove-support-usb-based-windows-7-installation-platform-specs/

Comment: Besides that there are No drivers for newer hardware and W7.

Comment: There was some talk over here on getting past the W7 install failure on skylake....https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/3h8vk0/build_help_installing_windows_7_on_skylake_z170/

Comment: I already have a windows7 machine on a KabyLake process and it works wonderfully.

Comment: I should add, the only difference between this new computer and my KabyLake is that the bios doesn't let me set Legacy boot.  I think maybe i need to create the disk in GPT.  I'm going to do that now and see if that makes the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Installation on new systems is blocked as per https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/windows-7-wont-work-intels-current-next-gen-cpus/. Once you get it installed, it works fine. There was a period where Microsoft blocked it, then let 7 install, then blocked it again.

A patch exists per [Extreme Tech](https://www.extremetech.com/computing/248069-unofficial-patch-unblocks-windows-7-8-1-updates-kaby-lake-ryzen). I have installed this [wufuc patch](https://github.com/zeffy/wufuc) once, and it worked as advertised, but please bear in mind it lasts just as long as Microsoft doesn't find a new way to block it.

Comment: No, its is NOT blocked.  Contrary to that article, i have Windows 7 working perfectly on KabyLake.  That article is not helpful